# Webhook in typeform.com

Tags: php, database, webhooks

I need save answers from my typeform to file or database. I read documencation [webhook](https://www.typeform.com/help/webhooks/). I created file on my domains: `example.pl/webhook`, and when I add my link to admin panel in typeform->webook, typeform returned me: [image]

What I must add to my folder `/webhook`, so that the script `typeform` can write responses to the file or database.

Comment: Ever solve the problem?

Comment: @jerrygarciuh No, I left this problem unresolved